# What makes nodes gradually move down?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Please carefully consider the following diagram. What makes the `\psframebox` nodes gradually move down?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{griddots=0}
\psset
{
    framearc=0.5,
    framesep=0.5,
    linewidth=0.5,
    colsep=1,
    rowsep=1,   
    mnode=r,
}

\def\A{\psframebox{\pspicture(2,1)\psframe*[linecolor=blue](2,1)\endpspicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\pspicture[showgrid=top](6,20)
\rput[tl](1,20){%
\psmatrix
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
\endpsmatrix}
\endpspicture
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Herbert's answer in the PSTricks' mailing list:

> which has nothing to do with PSTricks...
>
> ```
> \rput[tl](1,20){\offinterlineskip\psmatrix\A\\\A\\\A\\\A\\\A\\\endpsmatrix}
> ```

```
\documentclass[preview,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{griddots=0}
\psset
{
    framearc=0.5,
    framesep=0.5,
    linewidth=0.5,
    colsep=1,
    rowsep=1,   
    mnode=r,
}

\def\A{\psframebox{\pspicture(2,1)\psframe*[linecolor=blue](2,1)\endpspicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\pspicture[showgrid=top](6,20)
\rput[tl](1,20){%
\offinterlineskip
\psmatrix
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
\endpsmatrix}
\endpspicture
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following is my addition for those who are interested to know what causes the interlineskip.

```
% DG/SR modification begin - Nov. 27, 1998 - Patch 8
%\let\mscount\@multicnt
\ifx\mscount\@undefined\let\mscount\@multicnt\fi
% DG/SR modification end
\def\psmatrix{\begingroup{\ifnum0=`}\fi % Don't want to expand any &.
  \@ifnextchar[{\psmatrix@i}{\ifnum0=`{\fi}{}\psmatrix@ii}}
\def\psmatrix@i[#1]{%
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}{}%
  \psset{#1}%
  \psmatrix@ii}
\def\psmatrix@ii{%
  \KillGlue
  \edef\psm@beginmath{%
    \ifmmode$\m@th\ifinner\textstyle\else\displaystyle\fi\fi}%
  \edef\psm@endmath{\ifmmode$\fi}%
  \let\\\psm@cr
  \advance\psmatrixcnt by \@ne
  \def\psm@thenode{M-\the\psmatrixcnt-\the\psrow-\the\pscol}%
  \tabskip\z@
  \psrow=\@ne
  \pscol\z@
  \psset{shortput=tablr}%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup&%
  \begingroup
  \global\advance\pscol by \@ne
  \csname psrowhook\romannumeral\psrow\endcsname
  \csname pscolhook\romannumeral\pscol\endcsname
  \psm@beginnode##\psm@endnode\endgroup
  \cr}
%
\def\endpsmatrix{%
  \crcr\egroup\unskip\egroup
  \endgroup}
```

According to [David Carlisle's answer in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8552755#8552755):

> \lineskip glue is a TeX primitive feature of the way TeX constructs
>   vertical boxes

Comment: I am not trying to be rude, but to me this is a picture, a quote that "something" (what?) has nothing to do with PSTricks, and some code. I can't see how this answers the original question. (But then again, I don't know PSTricks....) Can you be a bit more specific, add some more explanation?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: My intent of putting Herbert's short answer (taken from the PSTricks' mailing list) here is to be regarded as a starting point from which you can elaborate more as well as to help others with the same problem. That is why I set it as a community wiki. If I did not put his answer here, how can I finalize my question because I need to make a single accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks. It still would be nice if you could add some more background and point out why this is relevant. For example, the OP asked what caused the problem. So far, nobody has answered this, except that "extra space" is added (not what causes it).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Hopefully, my update gives little enlightenment.

Comment: I think this greatly improves the answer.

Comment: I want to know whether or not this feature will still be kept unchanged in the next build of `pst-node`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is some extra vertical space added after the row separator.
Correction of -1bp:

```
\begin{preview}
\newdimen\rfix \rfix=1cm \advance\rfix-1bp
\pspicture[showgrid=top,rowsep=\rfix](6,20)
```

seems to fix this.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{griddots=0}
\psset
{
    framearc=0.5,
    framesep=0.5,
    linewidth=0.5,
    colsep=1,
    rowsep=1,   
    mnode=r,
}

\def\A{\psframebox{\pspicture(2,1)\psframe*[linecolor=blue](2,1)\endpspicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\newdimen\rfix \rfix=1cm \advance\rfix-1bp
\pspicture[showgrid=top,rowsep=\rfix](6,20)
\rput[tl](1,20){%
\psmatrix
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
    \A  \\
\endpsmatrix}
\endpspicture
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]